# extract name from email without using substr an instr

Tags: oracle

How to extract username from email without using instr and substr.I am working in oracle db.
I tried this

```
select regexp_replace(email,'^.*@') from students;
```

but i got output as domain name.pls help

Comment: What about regexp_substr?

Comment: same answer i got

Comment: Why can't you use SUBSTR and INSTR?  Is this code golf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select regexp_replace(email,'@.*$') from students
```

It replaces all starting from `@` till the end of line with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select regexp_substr(email, '[A-Z]{1,10}') REG_EXP from students;
```

Please note this query assumes that you are having only characters in your username (i.e before @ symbol) and it is of leng

if your user name is having the combination of both characters and numeric you can try the below code

```
select regexp_substr(email, '[0-9A-Z]{1,10}') REG_EXP from students;
```

Note: If you have lower case letters, this script will work and if your username has more than 10 characters please change {1,10} part of code accordingly

Comment: How about lower case letters? Or user name longer than 10 characters?